# I am having trouble with my SQL query in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, left-join, outer-join

What I am trying to do is get all records from `parts` and any records from `oelineitem` where `parts.id` is equal `owlineitems.part_id` as well I need a couple fields from the table `oe`.

I am guaranteed a row in `oe` for every row in `oelineitems` (many-to-one relation) but I am not guaranteed a row in `oelineitem` for every row in `parts`.  Even if there is no row in `oelineitem`, I need the row from `parts` to be in the dataset.

My query:

```
SELECT parts.partnumber, 
       parts.description, 
       parts.bin, 
       parts.obsolete, 
       orderitems.qty, 
       oe.transdate 
FROM   parts 
LEFT JOIN orderitems 
       ON parts.id = orderitems.parts_id
LEFT JOIN oe 
       ON orderitems.trans_id = oe.id 
WHERE  oe.customer_id <> 12228
ORDER  BY part.partnumber;
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the criteria from WHERE to ON:

```
SELECT parts.partnumber, 
       parts.description, 
       parts.bin, 
       parts.obsolete, 
       orderitems.qty, 
       oe.transdate 
FROM   parts 
LEFT JOIN orderitems 
       ON parts.id = orderitems.parts_id
LEFT JOIN oe 
       ON orderitems.trans_id = oe.id 
       AND oe.customer_id <> 12228
ORDER  BY part.partnumber;
```

You are outer-joining records. So in case there is no match you join a dummy record with all columns NULL. If you ask `WHERE  oe.customer_id <> 12228` you dismiss these records, so you remove all outer-joined records and are where you would have been with a mere inner join.

(Because `NULL <> 12228` results in null, not in true.)